# Динамически добавить Layout в Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Есть динамически созданный `LinearLayoyt`. Мне нужно добавить его в `LinearLayout`, объявленный в xml-разметке. Причем не один раз, а N-ное количество.

Меня немного удивило, что, оказывается, нельзя просто взять и добавить леяут в леяут несколько раз. При повторном клике на кнопку приложение вылатает с ошибкой. Все наверно догадались, что там в стектрейсе:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Мне просто жизненно необходимо добавить леяут в леяут. Как это можно реализовать?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */

LinearLayout lin;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Layout);

    final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    Button b1 = new Button(this);
    b1.setText("Knopka");
    b1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    layout.addView(b1);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          lin.addView(layout);
        }
    });

}
}





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SimpleTest"
    android:id="@+id/Button"
    />

<LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/Layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы каждый раз пытаетесь добавить один и тот же `Layout`, в первый раз прокатывает, а во второй раз ваш лейаут уже имеет родителя. Создавайте каждый раз новый лейаут и пихайте на здоровье:

```
@Override        
public void onClick(View v) {
   lin.addView(new Layout(...));        
}
```